# Why won't my code run?

Tags: python

## Ascii credits - http://www.chris.com/ascii

The code won't run in pyscripter for some reason only showing two chevron prompts please help me out? Thanks. Also if you think you find any problems(bugs) etc. with the code. feel free to correct me or correct it yourself,thanks.

```
     import random
     import time

    playagain = True
    def intro():



     print('You and your brave behind stare at the large dark forest infront of you.')
     time.sleep(2)
     print()
     print('Instead of ignoring the darkness and spookiness of the forest you decide to enter anyways.')
     time.sleep(2)
     print()
     print('You do not worry because you are a brave archer heralding a bow with deadly tipped arrows.')
     print()
     print('What is your name brave Archer')
     print()
     choice = input()
     print('That is a name which brings fear, ' + choice)
     print()

     def monsters():

    monster = ['''oo88888888boo
            `""88888888888bo
                ""888; `"Y888o
                   Y88;    "Y88.
                    "88.     `88b.    ,
                     `Yb      `888.   :8b
                       Yb    , `888.   88b
                        Y.    ` `"88.  Y8"8.
                         Y. `. b ``8b  :8 Y8.
           ,oooooooo      Yo :.`b`b`8;  8  8b
    ,ood8P""""""""88888oo  8b Y.:b:b:8;,8 ,:8.
,od88888bo  ` ,o.   """888o`8b`8 Y.8.88d8 : 8;
"""""""""""8oo`,. 'oo.   ""888b8b:8db8888 d :8 :;
          d8888boP , "Y88o. ""Y8888888888 8 d8.88
        o""""888888o``o'"88bood8888888888:8,;8888
      o"    ""8888888o."88888888" oooo `888d888:8
     d'    ,o8888888P88od88P""' ,d8888; Y888888:8
   ,8'     ood88888,dP"88       :888888 :88888;d;
   8'  ,o88""8888`8P   `"       888888P  8888d;8;
  d;,o8P" ,d888'oP'             "8888"    d88888boo
  8,88'  ,8888'88                 `' ,o8; "" Y88888888oooo.
 :88'   ,8888'dP,88o    :;          d88P    oooo88d888888888bo.
 `"    ,8888;,;:88888.  d8.        :8P'   ""'          :8888888888ooo
      ,88888 8,88. :88; 88;     ood"                    88888888888P"Y;
     oP d88;d;d888od"Y8  8;     ""                      :8P""Y88PYb8 :
    :P'd888`8'8b  ""Y88. 8'                             `"   `8"  YP 8
   ,P .:Y8Pd8,8Y88o.  :;                                     `"  o8 d;
  ,8'','8888;:8o   """Y8           ooood88888oooo.       o         dP
  8P  ,d88'8;:8"888oooo8;       ,o888888888888888888boo  `Y8oo.   dP
 :8bd88888 8':8ooo.  ""Yb     odP""          """888888888bo8P""'o8"
 """""8888 8 :8888888o. 8oooo888oooooooooo.       Y8888888888oo8"
     d8888 Y :bo     `""""888P"""         ""Ybo.    `"8888888""
    ,8`Y88.: :8"Y88oooooooo88.                `Ybo     Y8"
    dP'd88;:; 8o        `""Y8b                  `"b.   dP
    88`8:8;:; 88888booooood888.                   `8.  8'
   :8P:'Y88:b 8P            `8b                    `8d8'
   88 ',88888 Y8888ooooooP""""Yb                    `"
  ,8; o8888bY;8Yb '         ooo88b
  :8o8":;888'8;88bo,od8` '`'`'  Ybo
  d8"  d;888bP;o'`        ,.:o:'`"P o
  "'   8'8888d8b,;odP8;dP'`    o:;`'8 :o       '
       8 :8P8'88o`8P''    ooo'   ,oo" d8.dboo
      ,8 :`d88b,88od8888P"'   oo""  ,'" dP"88888
      :P  88888;8b 888;   oo8"'   ,P' ,8' d'88"8
      d;,dY88888.Y. Y8888""    odP' ,d" ,d'dP ,P
      8bP' Y8Y888d8o `Y8;  ood8P' ,dP  o8':P  :;
     ,P"   :8YY;88b"b  Y8888P"  o'"  o8P ,P   8  -hrr-
           `8d:`888b`bo `8b  ,o8"  ,dP' ,P   :;
            8;:dP88888Yb  Y888;   d8;  ,P    8
            8;:8 :8888b88. `Y8boo8P'  ,P    :;
            8b8' `88:;Y88"b. `Y888   ,P     8
            88'   Y88':88b."8o `"8b.oP     8'
            "'    :8Y :88888o"8o  :88o.  ,8'
                   8: 88;8Y88b88bod8"Y8oo8P
                   8.d':b8`8:P`"8888o. :8P
                   88'  Yd 88'   `"88888"
                  :8'   `8 dP       """'
                  `'     8o8
                         88''', '''  ___
  `-._~-.                                  / /_ "~o\  :Y
      \  \                                / : \~x.  ` ')
       ]  Y                              /  |  Y< ~-.__j
      /   !                        _.--~T : l  l<  /.-~
     /   /                 ____.--~ .   ` l /~\ \<|Y
    /   /             .-~~"        /| .    ',-~\ \L|
   /   /             /     .^   \ Y~Y \.^>/l_   "--'
  /   Y           .-"(  .  l__  j_j l_/ /~_.-~    .
 Y    l          /    \  )    ~~~." / `/"~ / \.__/l_
 |     \     _.-"      ~-{__     l  :  l._Z~-.___.--~
 |      ~---~           /   ~~"---\_  ' __[>
 l  .                _.^   ___     _>-y~
  \  \     .      .-~   .-~   ~>--"  /
   \  ~---"            /     ./  _.-'
    "-.,_____.,_  _.--~\     _.-~
                ~~     (   _}
                        `. ~(
                          )  \
                         /,`--'~\--''' , '''
                _ ___                /^^\ /^\  /^^\_
    _          _@)@) \            ,,/ '` ~ `'~~ ', `\.
  _/o\_ _ _ _/~`.`...'~\        ./~~..,'`','',.,' '  ~:
 / `,'.~,~.~  .   , . , ~|,   ,/ .,' , ,. .. ,,.   `,  ~\_
( ' _' _ '_` _  '  .    , `\_/ .' ..' '  `  `   `..  `,   \_
 ~V~ V~ V~ V~ ~\ `   ' .  '    , ' .,.,''`.,.''`.,.``. ',   \_
  _/\ /\ /\ /\_/, . ' ,   `_/~\_ .' .,. ,, , _/~\_ `. `. '.,  \_
 < ~ ~ '~`'~'`, .,  .   `_: ::: \_ '      `_/ ::: \_ `.,' . ',  \_
  \ ' `_  '`_    _    ',/ _::_::_ \ _    _/ _::_::_ \   `.,'.,`., \-,-,-,_,_,
   `'~~ `'~~ `'~~ `'~~  \(_)(_)(_)/  `~~' \(_)(_)(_)/ ~'`\_.._,._,'_;_;_;_;_; '''
    ,  '''  |\___/|
            (,\  /,)\
            /     /  \
           (@_^_@)/   \
            W//W_/     \
          (//) |        \
        (/ /) _|_ /   )  \
      (// /) '/,_ _ _/  (~^-.
    (( // )) ,-{        _    `.
   (( /// ))  '/\      /      |
   (( ///))     `.   {       }
    ((/ ))    .----~-.\   \-'
             ///.----..>   \
              ///-._ _  _ _} '''


, '''
            / o       o \
           /   \     /   \
          /     )-"-(     \
         /     ( 6 6 )     \
        /       \ " /       \
       /         )=(         \
      /   o   .--"-"--.   o   \
     /    I  /  -   -  \  I    \
 .--(    (_}y/\       /\y{_)    )--.
(    ".___l\/__\_____/__\/l___,"    )
 \                                 /
  "-._      o O o O o O o      _,-"
      `--Y--.___________.--Y--'
         |==.___________.==| ''']


    print('You walk through the forest slowly...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('You hear a crack as if a twig broke..')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('The creature leaps out from the shadows!')
    time.sleep(5)
    print()
    print(random.choice(monster))
    print('You must engage the creature!')

     def battle():

    attack = [poison, fire, lightning, ice, greatbow]
    gold = [1,2,3]
    print('You ready your bow as you choose which tipped arrow to use embued with magic..')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('You strung your bow with the ' + random.choice(attack) + ' arrow')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('You take down the foe as he slowly tumbles to the ground!')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('The bigger they are the harder they fall')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Would you like to enter deeper into the forest or flee while you can, you collected ' + gold + ' gold stacks this time around')
    playagain = input()
    while playagain == 'yes':
    return intro
    return monsters
    return battle
    else: exit()
```

Comment: The indentation for the code seems to be wrong. Since indentation is significant in python, we can't debug the code in it's current form.

Comment: Being more specific would help to get your question answered more quickly. Please point out errors or other problems with the code and don't just paste all the content of your script.

Comment: Please modify your code to make it more minimal. At the moment, combined with your incorrect indentation a lot of code makes it hard to debug. Things like the long string of 'monsters' are just not necessary.

Comment: https://anonfiles.com/file/e2fae09101124510d03d0f6dcd5f0b20 heres my program. check it out there.

Comment: You never actually *call* any of your functions

Answer (score 0):

Make a list into string or some data type according to your need. For-example

```
attack = ["poison", "fire", "lightning", "ice", "greatbow"]
```

Secondly change the  int `gold` to str in this line given below:

```
print('Would you like to enter deeper into the forest or flee while you can, you collected ' + str(gold) + ' gold stacks this time around')
```

I am using python2.7 , change also `'yes'` into `"yes"`

```
    playagain = raw_input('Choose a number')
    while playagain == "yes":
        return intro
        return monsters
        return battle
    else: exit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    battle()
```

I don't know which one of method you want to call but I called `battle()` method and it run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Right first of all change all the `input` to `raw_input`. Also I guess the idea is to start from the `intro` function, then move to the `monsters` function and then to the `battle` function. Although you have defined them fine, you do not call them anywhere. What you could do for example is call the `monsters` function from the `intro` function, and then the `battle` function from the `monsters` function similarly